# Docusign - how to integrate docusign for multiple users each having different docusign credentials and multiple customers

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I have an app were there are 2 kinds of users.
A builder and an owner.

Now there is a centralized platform that I am building, were each builder who have their own docu sign account with them, will register. And then provide with a docusign URL (I am not sure what that is), and the owner then clicks on the link, once they are logged in to their part of the system. They sign the document using docusign and the builder gets the corresponding response in the centralized system.

Is this approach can be done using docusign? Or the working of this is completely different?

Answer (score 1):

You're likely referring to embedded signing vs remote signing from what I understood from your description.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/embedding/

In embedded signing, your app will take care of authenticating the users on DocuSign's behalf.

Comment: from your document link, it seems I want embedded signing. What are the details I need to initiate this process?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The Builders are the DocuSign `senders`. As you say, they have the DocuSign accounts that will be integrated into your system.

The owners are DocuSign `recipients`. More specifically `Signer Recipients.`

The owners do not sign into DocuSign at all. They may register (and login) themselves with your app, that's a different issue.

When appropriate, the owners click a link on your app to sign documents.

You then have some options: did the builder initiate a signing request for the owner to sign at some point in the future? Or is the signing request initiated when the owner decides that they want a document generated that they will then sign? (Or both?)

When it comes time for signing, if the signing ceremony is presented by your app to the owner, we call that `embedded signing`.

If the builder initiates a document to be signed by the owner, then the quickest technique is to immediately send a signing request (by email or SMS) directly to the owner. That's called `remote signing` by DocuSign. (The other way to do it is to wait until the next time the owner logs into your app. I would not recommend this since it would tend to slow down the completion of the signing process.)